# Error in stitcher() in OpenCv

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, computer-vision, image-stitching

I have this code:

```
#include <opencv2\stitching\stitcher.hpp>

int Stitching()
{
Stitcher m_stitcher = m_stitcher.createDefault(false);

vector<Mat> images; 
Mat img1 = imread("0.jpg"); //read image 0
Mat img2 = imread("1.jpg"); //read image 1
Mat Result;

//add images to the array
images.push_back(img1);
images.push_back(img2);

m_stitcher.stitch(images, Result);
imwrite("panorama.jpg",Result);
return 0;
}
```

After build I get this error:

> Error 4   error C2248: 'cv::Stitcher::Stitcher' : cannot access private
>   member declared in class
>   'cv::Stitcher'    C:\Users\Desktop\Projects\SamplePanorama -
>   PanoramaStitch\SamplePanorama \StitchEngine.cpp   602

What should i add to make the stitch() work correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that your class `Stitcher` does not have a public constructor. If this were a class you owned, you would need to give it a public constructor in order to be able to construct an instance of `Stitcher`. However, it seems that this is a third party library, a quick google search tells you about the presence of this method in [`Stitcher`](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/modules/stitching/include/opencv2/stitching/stitcher.hpp?rev=6769#L64):

```
static Stitcher createDefault(bool try_use_gpu = false);
```

In order to create an instance of `Stitcher` you would probably have to do something like:

```
Stitcher m_stitcher = Stitcher::CreateDefault();
```

Edit:
In order to fix your linker errors, you probably need to add the correct lib files to the list of inputs to your linker. This link should help you set that up, http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide

Comment: i did try the createDefault() function. Getting this error:error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: enum cv::Stitcher::Status __thiscall cv::Stitcher::stitch(class cv::_InputArray const &,class cv::_OutputArray const &)" (?stitch@Stitcher@cv@@QAE?AW4Status@12@ABV_InputArray@2@ABV_OutputArray@2@@Z) referenced in function "public: int __thiscall CStitchEngine::PanoramaStitch(void)" (?PanoramaStitch@CStitchEngine@@QAEHXZ)

Comment: and this one too: error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class cv::Stitcher __cdecl cv::Stitcher::createDefault(bool)" (?createDefault@Stitcher@cv@@SA?AV12@_N@Z) referenced in function "public: int __thiscall CStitchEngine::PanoramaStitch(void)" (?PanoramaStitch@CStitchEngine@@QAEHXZ)

Comment: @Vinshi you try to access static member (constructor) with wrong operator - `.` instead of `::`. Look at answer again and read carefully.

Comment: Also, are you sure you've set everything up correct? I think you need to build the opencv source code and then add the lib files as linker inputs. Have you done that? Alternatively, this would probably be easier http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985676/setting-up-opencv-and-lib-files